# How to get gauge chart in vue-google-charts to work - alternatives?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-visualization, google-gauges

In my vue project, I want to display the NPS score in the form of a gauge chart. The easiest way was to use vue-google-charts. Unfortunately, it seems like this type is not implemented.

vue-google-charts are working on my project. If I stick with the "ColumnChart". When I try to use the gauge chart nothing is displayed and I get an error in the console.

```
      type="Gauge"
      :packages="packages"
      :data="chartData"
      :options="chartOptions"
    />
```

as well as:

```
      type="gauge"
      :data="chartData"
      :options="chartOptions"
    />
```

are not working.

Any help is appreciated. If someone has a working example of how to use the google API directly I would do that. But I was not able to get that approach to work.

Comment: do you look to something like https://v-charts.js.org/#/en/gauge?

Comment: Yes, the problem there is, that I cant color code the areas. My values are going from -100 (red) to +100 (green).

Comment: you need to load the `gauge` package for google charts, see [load-additional-packages](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-google-charts#load-additional-packages)

Answer (score 1):

The right way of doing it was by mixing upper and lower case.

```
<GChart
:settings="{ packages: ['corechart', 'gauge'] }"
type="Gauge"
:data="raiting.NPS"
:options="chartOptions"
/>
```

Thank you very much @WhiteHat. I tried it before, but only since you pointed me, that it is the right way, I tried the mix of upper and lower case.